# sorl.thumbnail not showing img in admin panel

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using django 1.10 and last sorl.thumbnail
Here is my **models.py**

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
class StockImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='stock', blank=True, null=True,
                              verbose_name=_('Image'))
```

here is **admin.py**

```
from sorl.thumbnail.admin import AdminImageMixin
class StockImageInline(AdminImageMixin, admin.StackedInline):
    model = StockImage
    extra = 1    

@admin.register(Stock)
class StockAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    group_fieldsets = True
    list_display = ('title', 'city', 'start_date', 'finish_date', 'unlimited', 'publish')
    inlines = [
        StockImageInline,
    ]
```

Comment: Reason was in old "Pillow" version. Thank's.

Comment: What version of pillow did you upgrade to? I am having the same issue with Python 3.5.2, sorl-thumbnail==12.3, Pillow==4.1.1

Comment: Python3.6 install sorl by this link "-e git+https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail.git#egg=sorl-thumbnail" pillow-4.0.0